# How to get variable names as characters inside a list

Tags: r

I have an unnamed list of variables, I want to input this list to a function and get the names of the variables.

```
l <- list(cars,mtcars)
fun <- function(l){...}
f(l)
 # c("cars", "mtcars")
```

I have been playing around with `deparse(substitute(...))` with no success.
Any ideas?

Here a few things I have tried:

```
l <- list(cars,mtcars)

lapply(l,function(i){deparse(substitute(i))})
lapply(l,function(i){deparse(substitute(i,parent.frame()))})
lapply(l,function(i){deparse(substitute(i,parent.frame(sys.nframe())))})

Map(function(i){deparse(substitute(i))},l)
Map(function(i){deparse(substitute(i,parent.frame(sys.nframe())))},l)

foo <- function(a, ...) {
  arg <- deparse(substitute(a))
  dots <- substitute(list(...))[-1]
  c(arg, sapply(dots, deparse))
}
foo(cars)
do.call("foo",l)

foo2 <- function(x) deparse(substitute(x))
foo2(mtcars)
do.call("foo",l)

foo3 <- function(a, ...) {
  sapply(match.call(expand.dots=TRUE)[-1], deparse)
}
foo3(cars)
do.call("foo3",l)
```

Comment: You can't do that. Once you've created the unnamed list of objects, there's no connection between those objects and their original names.

Comment: `lapply(l, names)` will give you the column names of the two data frames.

Comment: `l <- list(cars = cars, mtcars = mtcars); names(l)` Is this what you are getting at?

Comment: @Vlo I was trying to do it without naming the list